# Is the Player's Handbook required to choose feats?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, books

I'm trying to use [the Basic Rules](https://web.archive.org/web/20220119161420/https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/basicrules?x=dnd/basicrules) for 5th edition to create a level 3 character (we're trying out 5e today). I don't have a PHB (yet). Chapter 6 from the basic rules (which is one page) seems to have about the only info on multiclassing (which I wanted to try) and more importantly feats (which every character would need, right?). About the latter it just says:

> See chapter 6 of the Player’s Handbook for more information.

Does this mean **the PHB is effectively required to choose feats** and find out about their effects?

I've tried to answer my own question. I've searched the basic rules for "feat" (way too many results to be useful) and "feats" (the only helpful info is quoted above). I've also searched with Google (e.g. [this query](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20choose%20feats%20D&D%205th%20edition)), which mostly leads to reviews and forum posts.

Comment: @sadaqah Just to clarify, actually all classes get five ability increases at the same levels; it's just that some classes get extra ones in addition to that (two for the Fighter, one for the Thief).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Yes, you need a players handbook.** Based on experiences with previous editions, there will be a lot of books expanding those rules, especially new feats, but the PHB lays the groundwork.

Please note that both feats and multi classing are *optional* rules that you don't need to play the game.

Comment: My recommendation would be to play with the basic rules, then if you like the game and want to expand, simply retcon your character with the new stuff when you get the books for it.

Comment: Not only are feats optional, but they're designed such that PCs with and without feats can be in the same party without balance issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was indeed correct. I've now also seen how it *does* work with feats in 5e, it's basically like @DoStuffZ says in his comment to the question; perhaps it'd be worth it to add that info to the answer. In any case: thanks again!